# How to convert a list to a dict and concatenate values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list with schema as shown below:

```
list=[('a',2),('b',4),('a',1),('c',6)]
```

What I would like to do is convert it to a dict using the first value of each pair as key,I would also like pairs with the same key to be concatenated.For the above the result would be:

```
dict={ 'a':[2,1] , 'b':[4] , 'c':[6]  }
```

I don't care about the order of the concatenated values,meaning we could also have `'a':[1,2]`.

How could this be done in python?

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to iterate through the list and create the dictionary.
If a key exists, append the element to the key value.
Else create an entry to the dictionary with an one element list. `defaultdict` can also come in handy, to avoid many `if-else` conditions

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```py
l = [('a',2),('b',4),('a',1),('c',6)]

d = {}

for item in l:
    if item[0] in d:
        d[item[0]].append(item[1])
    else:
        d[item[0]] = [item[1]]

print(d) # {'a': [2, 1], 'b': [4], 'c': [6]}
```

To make it cleaner you could use `defaultdict` and 2 `for` iterators:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

l = [('a',2),('b',4),('a',1),('c',6)]

d = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for key, val in l:
    d[key].append(val)

print(dict(d)) # {'a': [2, 1], 'b': [4], 'c': [6]})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `setdefault` method on `dict` to set a list as the default entry if a key is not in the dictionary yet:

```py
l=[('a',2),('b',4),('a',1),('c',6)]
d = {}

for k, v in l:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

d
{'a': [2, 1], 'b': [4], 'c': [6]}
```